# Using innerHTML for partial HTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

the following function

```
<script>
function new_par()
{
var beginning="<input id=";
document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML=beginning;
}
</script>
```

produces no output, although if I remove the "<" sign, it does.  Presumably the javascript avoids an output that would destroy the html page, but would there be anyway to force the output?

Comment: wild guess: Is your javascript outputting as HTML rather than plain text?

Comment: Please format your code correctly by adding a newline before and after it, highlighting it, and pressing ctrl+k.

Comment: In the html source there is nothing.

Comment: What are you expecting as a result, when setting invalid HTML to an element? Are you trying to show some markup in another element?

Comment: Your setting HTML. `<input id=` is not valid HTML.

Comment: @Teemu The result I am expecting is that <input id= appears in the html code.  The reason why I am doing is that I need something like <input id=x> where x is a variable, which somehow doesn't work even though the expected html code should be legal.  So I am trying to debug with smaller portion of string.

Comment: For debugging use the console (`console.log(beginning)`). Also, you might solve your real problem faster if you asked about it specifically instead of why your debugging code doesn't work.

Comment: Browsers will auto-fix any invalid markup before placing it on a page. An empty element with incomplete tag can't be fixed, hence it's ignored. Probably you need to concatenate strings to achieve the original goal of yours. Something like `var beginning='<input id="' + varContainingID + '">';`

Comment: Posted code does not need `<script>` tags.

Comment: @JJJ Well, I didn't know how to get a "minimal non-working example" out of the original code I was writing so that I could post a legitimate question.  But you are right, by trying to write a minimal example, I ended up writing a code that works (although I still haven't understood the errors in the original code I wrote).  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Teemu Yes, closing the tag made it work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning it to a node's innerHTML property. When you plug the string into the DOM it's trying to parse it as though it were HTML. If you were to simply add it as a text node it would appear.

```
var beginning="<input id=''";
document.body.textContent = beginning;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2patzyo1/

**Edit**: upon looking again at your question, if you are *trying* to get the input element to appear on the page, the string you're using isn't proper HTML because you never closed the tag. When the browser runs into it, it tries to parse and render it, but because it isn't valid it gives up. This will work:

```
var beginning="<input id=''>";
document.body.innerHTML = beginning;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2patzyo1/1/